# Thoughts about allowing arithmetic with infinitesimals to (mostly) solve limits, can it be done without contradictions?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, number-systems, nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

I am currently working on a project for school where I would like to create an arithmetic framework that would make it easier to solve limits. Suppose we have a function $f:\mathbb{R}\smallsetminus  \{a\} \to \mathbb{R}$, where we would like to evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a^{+}} [f(x)]$ or $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a^{-}} [f(x)]$. If $a^+$ or $a^-$ were numbers, informally "infinitesimally larger or smaller than $a$", they would be part of the domain for the functions and as such, you could just plug them in. That would be quite convenient. Additionally, I would like to propose that the distributive property applies to these infinitesimals. Although I have read about similar things before (non-standard analysis, hyperreals), I have yet to see a strictly defined framework for such numbers.

The first reasonable step on this journey is to accept the existance of a positive infinitesimal, i.e. a "number" $\varepsilon$ with the following quality: $\forall \delta\in \mathbb{R}^{+}:0<\varepsilon<\delta$. This seems axiomatic in that it simply has to be accepted for anything else to make sense. Now based on this definition, it seems certain limits also have to be changed a bit, specifically, limits that would traditionally approach 0 would have to approach this number instead:

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to 0^{\pm}} n=\pm\varepsilon\approx 0$.

Some other interesting consequences of this definition seem to be that: $k\cdot \varepsilon=\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon^k=\varepsilon$.

It seems you can work out some basic things like this without much issue. However, there seems to be situations where things begin to break down. For example, a very convenient consequence of the definition above is: $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{f(x)}{x}=\frac{f(\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon}=\infty$, for some strictly positive function $f$. But we also know that $k\cdot \varepsilon=\varepsilon$. So what happens in a situation such as:

$\displaystyle \frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon}$

It seems to me this should be $1$, but maybe that would lead to some contradiction down the road. That segways out of the lengthy introduction into my main question: when constructing such a framework, how can we make sure it will not lead to contradictions down the road? Mainly, I would like to use these "numbers" to solve limits, so obviously the number system has to be defined in such a way where all kinds of limits evaluate to the same thing they would in standard analysis. Also, what kind of axioms/postulations would I need to "prove" some of the qualtities for the infinitesimal that I showed here? "Proof by intuition" isn't very rigorous...

Comment: [Nonstandard analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonstandard_analysis) is a very well-documented and studied framework. It can be defined within ZF set-theory, so it is no more prone to contradictions than most of mainstream mathematics.

Comment: "Although I have read about ... hyperreals), I have yet to see a strictly defined framework for such numbers." Have you searched the internet for "definition of hyperreals" and been unsatisfied with all definitions you've found? If not, I would try that.

Comment: @MarkS., I have looked around a bit on the web. What I have been unsatisfied with specifically is how they would work with this specific application (namely limits). Suppose I give you $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{2x^{2}-3x+5}{x}$, and ask you to evaluate it. I want to create a system where I could just plug in $0^+$ ($\varepsilon$) and evaluate it immediately. Does that already exist, and I have just been unsuccessful when looking for it?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "immediately", I'd say that's the whole point of the use of hyperreals in Nonstandard Analysis. For more details on how to do calculus with infinitesimals like Robinson's Hyperreals, see [Calculus Made Easy](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/33283) by Thompson for a raw intuition-based presentation, or [Elementary Calculus: An Infinitesimal Approach](https://people.math.wisc.edu/~hkeisler/calc.html) by Keisler for a semi-formal presentation.

Comment: You write that you are trying to "create an arithmetic framework that would make it easier to solve limits" but which approach exactly are you trying to simplify?  How were you taught to "solve limits" and which aspect of it do you feel should be simplified?  Were you taught to use epsilon-delta to find limits?

Comment: @MikhailKatz, I would like to simplify the process of solving one-sided limits. For example, suppose I give you some weird limit like:

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \pi^+} \frac{(x-\pi)^{2}}{\sin^2 x}$

In school up until this point, we have been taught to plug in values that get closer and closer to $\pi$ and then look at the function's behaviour. However, I do not find this satisfying (also it's hard without a calculator). But if $\pi^+$ were in the function's domain, you could just plug it in and evaluate.

Some functions would have to be redefined to allow infinitesimal arguments.

Comment: Since $\sin^2$ is periodic with period $\pi$, the sensible thing to do here is to make a change of variables $y=x-\pi$ and then your limit becomes $\lim_{y\to0^+}\frac{y^2}{\sin^2 y}$.  Do you know how to evaluate such a limit?

Comment: As far as "redefining functions to allow infinitesimal arguments", this is not a practical thing to do.  It is more practical to show that *every* function can be so extended.  See the related discussion of the [transfer principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_principle#Transfer_principle_for_the_hyperreals).

Comment: No, to my somewhat untrained eye it just looks like we have the same problem but with a different variable. In my "system", it could be evaluated as:

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \pi^+} \frac{(x-\pi)^{2}}{\sin^2 x}=\frac{(\pi^+-\pi)^2}{\sin^2\pi^+}=\frac{0^+}{0^+}=1$

Here, $\pi^+=\pi+\varepsilon$.

If we disregard the strictness for a moment and think about it intuatively: "a number infinitesimally larger than $\pi$ $(\pi^+)$ minus $\pi$" would be infinitesimally close to zero. Similarly, $\sin$ of an argument infinitesimally close to zero should be infinitesimally close to 0 as well.

Comment: How would you calculate the limit $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin 2x}x$?

Comment: Assuming the limit exists:

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin2x}{x}\approx \lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \frac{\sin2x}{x}=\frac{2\sin x\cdot\cos x}{x}=2\cdot\frac{\varepsilon\cdot1^{-}}{\varepsilon}=2^{-}\approx 2$

But I think I see your concern. If I were to just immediately plug in $0^+$, then  $\sin 2x$ would've simplified to $\varepsilon$, but that doesn't really make sense since that limit would be 1 according to my prior definition of the number $\varepsilon$, unless we accept that certain infinitesimals can be larger than others, which is itself a contradiction.

Comment: No, it is not a contradiction at all.  Infinitesimals can come in all sorts of sizes.  You may want to peruse [hyperreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number).

Comment: Thank you! I am mathematically illiterate, so I have hard time navigating the page properly (meaning I do not know what to even look for). If you don't mind, could you please tell me which subheadings deal with infinitesimals in "different sizes"? So that I have somewhere to start reading.

Comment: I added a source to [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4852729/72694).

Comment: Hello, again! @MikhailKatz. I hope it's okay that I tagged you.

I have been looking in to this a bit more recently and have noticed that for certain limits, a definition such as "$\sin k\varepsilon = k\varepsilon$" simply does not hold. It has come to my attention that this happens because our approximation, although infinitesimally close to every other approximation, is not good enough. Do you think it's even possible to define trignonometric functions well for infinitesimal inputs, or do their values depend on the context?

Comment: I answered there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leibniz's great insight was that when one introduces infinitesimals in a number system, they should behave in the "same way" as "ordinary" numbers do.  Thus, if $\epsilon>0$ is infinitesimal then $k\epsilon > \epsilon$ for $k>1$ and $\epsilon^k <\epsilon$, etc.  This enabled him to develop a workable system of infinitesimals that can be used in analysis.

The idea of infinitesimals of different order was widely discussed by Leibniz.  At wiki, the only related discussion I have been able to find is [Cauchy's Cours d'Analyse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cours_d%27Analyse#Chapter_2).